# how to handle NSLocal Notification in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, alarm

- For multiple Alarm Notification Alert?
- If Application is Running in Background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog(@"app not running");
    }
    else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
        NSLog(@"App is running");

    }else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){
        NSLog(@"App is running in background");
    }
}
```

In Addition to JAGAT's answer for iOS 8+ you need to ask for permission to register for listening to local notifications. And you can user this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{

}
```

And for permisson do this:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                                         settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                                                         categories:nil]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method in `AppDelegate.m` class.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog(@"app not running");
    }
    else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
        NSLog(@"App is running");

    }else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){
        NSLog(@"App is running in background");
    }
}
```

May be this is helpful for you to handle local notification in background.